# Are there magazines similar to Spotlight, Adesso, Écoute, Ecos for foreign speakers to learn German?

Tags: learning

Some years ago I learned some Italian by studying on one's own. Than I found the `Adesso` magazine very helpful.

Some years later, when I learned the basics of Dutch, I was really missing a similar source.

Edit:

The concept of [Spotlight Verlag](https://www.spotlight-verlag.de/adwords/de/spotlight/) is to present authentic texts in foreign language with supplying translations of some of the difficult words.  Most of the text are rather actual and they try to select words which occur in different articles to teach them in different context.

In earlier times there were Compact Cassettes with reading some of the articles. Later these where replaced by DVDs.

Some articles about grammar.

In short it is a rather living presentation and I enjoyed it.

Spotlight is the brand of the magazines teaching English.

The other magazines for German are [Écoute (french)](http://www.ecoute.de/), [ECOS (spanisch)](http://www.ecos-online.de/) and  [ADESSO (Italian)](http://www.adesso-online.de/).

Comment: I've never heard of them. Could you add what properties in these magazines that you're loóking for?

Comment: +1, sounds very useful!

Comment: Very good question. Is there a specific source language? If not, this might become a collection (and therefore maybe community wiki material).

Comment: DER SPIEGEL special ist sehr gut oder GEO

Comment: @burbuja Ist das ein einmaliges Sonderheft oder eine Reihe?

Comment: es ist ein Monatsheft / Sonderheft DES SPIEGEL zur verschiedenen Themen auf sehr hohem Niveau, hoffentlich erscheint er noch. Habe ihn einige Jahre gekauft, obwohl er für mich in Tschechien sauteuer war. Es hat sich gelohnt.:)

Comment: wenn nicht, kauf dir ab und zu DEN SPIEGEL, oder lies es online.
http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/

Comment: Vorsicht: SPIEGEL Online ist nicht auf dem gleichen sprachlichen (und inhaltlichen) Niveau wie die gedruckte Ausgabe.

Answer (score 5):

*Ich kenne keine der im folgenden aufgezählten Publikationen, aber vielleicht kann jemand in den Kommentaren eigene Erfahrungen dazu berichten.*

---

[**Deutsch perfekt**](http://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/fragen-antworten/english/learning-german)

> Deutsch perfekt is an ideal blend of professional journalism and successful language training. Interesting texts and topical issues provide important insights into life in Germany, Austria and Switzerland, and at the same time form the backbone of Deutsch perfekt's unique language service.

---

[**Klar & Deutlich**](http://www.spassamlesenverlag.de/cms/website.php)

ist eine "leicht lesbare" Zeitung auf Deutsch.

---

[**Scholastic Foreign Languages Magazines**](http://teacher.scholastic.com/products/classmags/mgm_german.htm#)

> Scholastic German Magazines are the most engaging foreign language resources for adolescent German students of any proficiency level.

Comment: Ich wollte schon vorschlagen, links hinzuzufügen. Anfangs hatte ich sie hinter den Überschriften übersehen.