# Magazines and documentaries for speaking German with subtitles

Tags: learning, reference

Could you please name some documentaries, radio stations or magazines with easy German vocabulary and clear pronunciation?

Comment: Related: [Are there magazines similar to Spotlight, Adesso, Écoute, Ecos for foreign speakers to learn German?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/842/1224) - [Online resource which has easy German to read with its English translation](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1414/1224) - [Are there any english subtitled german intellectual shows?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4781/1224)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not related to Yabla.

But I have appreciated their video demos very much. There are subtitles, both german and english that you can switch on and off. The speed of the video can be slowered. And all videos are done by genuine german people, and often real video content. I think something like 300 or more videos, i don't remember. You should at least [give a try there german.yabla.com](http://german.yabla.com). And I am tempted to subscribe personnally, I just wait to have a little more time during the week.

**Update:** 
It's been several weeks now that I have been listening to [DeutschlandFunk](http://deutschlandfunk.radio.de/). It's been the best radio so far for learning, because there's not too much music, and not too much advertising, and **their accent is really clear: really understandable pronunciation**. ( I tried KlassikRadio and XFM917 before, both were fine but there were far more music than speech).

Answer (score 2):

[Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw.de/dw/0,,2469,00.html) has a variety of Radio and streaming TV shows which are either subtitled or have downloadable transcripts and/or exercises. There's something for almost every learner there, I've found it very useful but not quite capable of standing on its own.